# Move maento to the another path

Tags: magento2, migration

Hi I have installed the developed the magento 2 in the path domain.com/new folder and developed in that path. Now I want push the installed file to the public_html file without affecting the code.

Comment: You want to push your complete code to ur domain.com instead of domain.com/new folder right

Comment: yes. without affecting the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Files**

Navigate to app/etc and rename di.xml and config.php file.

Now you are hit your domain url it will redirect to installation page and then enter all credential and current database name

**Using Database**

Step 1 : Copy and paste all your magento file in your public_html path

Step 2 : Go to database and find **"core_config_data"** table

[image]

Step 3 : Replace your domain url in "web/unsecure/base_url" and "web/secure/base_url" or admin panel have option change secure&unsecure base url
[image]

Step 4 : Run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: i moved my magento from /path/oldfolder to /path/newfolder, i maintain my domain, just changue the domain read  the new folder instead the old folder. I did it using the "Using Database" method that you mention, but when i try to acces to the admin, i got "too many redirections" error. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy all content/files(new folder in case of you)  to public_html folder.
You just need to change/set the Base url and base url secure

- From backend store->configurations->web Base URLs (http://domain.com)
- open up database table core_config_data and find  under path web/unsecure/base_url change its value to  your domain name (domain.com) and path web/secure/base_url value to (https://domain.com)
- clean cache